# Put all the element of a mysql table into javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I would like to store my mysql table into a javascript array. I wish to push into my array every element of the table so I would be left with an array like this :

```
array[0] = [question: information01, answer: information02...]
array[1] = [question: information11, answer: information12...]
```

With my following code, all the elements of my table are stocked into the first element of my array, which gives me this :

```
array[0] = [[question: information01, answer: information02...], [question: information11, answer: information12...]]
```

and so the array has a size of 0 instead of size of the mysql table (I hope it makes sense)

```
var availableQuestions = [];
ajaxRequest("GET","../controller.php?func=get_enigme", (enigme) => {
    var enigmeAll = JSON.parse(enigme);
    for (var i=0; i < enigmeAll.length; i++){
        availableQuestions.push(enigmeAll[i]);
    }
});
function ajaxRequest(type,url,callback,data=""){
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open(type, url);

request.onload = function () {
    switch (request.status){
        case 200:
        case 201: //console.log(request.responseText);
                    callback(request.responseText);
            break;
        default: console.log(request.status);
    }
};

request.send(data);
}
```

When I do a `console.log(availableQuestions.length)` in my ajaxRequest it is saying 2, but when I do it outside of my function it is saying `length = 0`. Which I don't understand.
Does anyone have an answer to my problem ?
Thank you very much in advance for your answers,

EDIT : I just put my parse into another array with my for loop which of course didn't help..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var availableQuestions = [];
ajaxRequest("GET","../controller.php?func=get_enigme", (enigme) => {
    var enigmeAll = JSON.parse(enigme);
    for (var i=0; i < enigmeAll.length; i++){
        availableQuestions.push([enigmeAll[i]]);
    }
});
```

try this

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't change anything

Comment: "availableQuestions.push([enigmeAll[i]])"look closely to this line and execute with push([enigmeall[i]]), this works right

Comment: I did availableQuestions.push([enigmeAll[i]]) but it displays same as before.
Also I edit my question maybe the error is coming from there :
When I do a console.log(availableQuestions.length) in my ajaxRequest function it is saying 2, but when I do it outside of my function it is saying length = 0. Which I don't understand

Answer (score -1):

The response you are getting is not in the right format for your parsing to work. You would probably want to end up with something like:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        question: "Question1"
        answer: "Answer1"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        question: "Question2"
        answer: "Answer2"
    }
]
```

For that to happen, the response you get from the ajax call should look similar. If you have control over how the response is built, it would be better to go ahead and modify it. If not, you're gonna need to extend the logic of parsing that response a bit, since it contains a lot of tokens that aren't really necessary (I'm seeing a lot of indexes as keys, probably as a result of stringifying some raw data that comes from the table).

Comment: Thank you for your help.
For console.log(enigme) before JSON.parse I have this : 
[{"id":1,"0":1,"question":"\"Information.\"","1":"\"Information\"","reponse":"[\"answer\"]","2":"[\"answer\"]","type":"enigme","3":"enigme"},...]

for console.log(enigmeAll) after JSON I have : 
0: {0: 1, 1: `"Information"`, 2: '["answer"]', 3: 'enigme', id: 1, question: `"Information."`, reponse: '["answer"]', type: 'enigme'}
1: {0: 32 1: '"Information."', 2: '["answer1","answer2"]', 2: 'enigme', id: 2, question: 'Information."', reponse: '["answer1","answer2"]', type: 'enigme'}

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
Unfortunately I am not responsible of the database so I can't change all the indexes.
I can change the response but as I didn't write as well the code I don't really understand what to change. Should I built my own response ?

Comment: Well, it looks like your result contains duplicate values for every field but the id, one with the actual real key (e.g. question, response, type) and one with some indexes, but the right values. This might be a result of converting an array directly into an object somewhere between the DB fetch and seding back the response. If you say you don't have any control on how the response looks like, you'd need to parse the response and eliminate entries with indexes as keys. Since you are using JSON.parse, you could use the 2nd argument of JSON.parse (the reviver argument). Example below.

Comment: var enigmeAll = JSON.parse(enigme, (key, value) => {
    if (key === '') { return value; }
    return isNaN(Number(key)) ? value : undefined;
});

This second argument to JSON.parse lets you edit the values that you are going to receive as a result from parsing and even eliminates them completely if you return undefined for some of them. The first return is necessary because of the way the reviver argument works. It parses through all key-value pairs, ending with a call to the 'this' instance of the object, denoted by a key-value pair, where the key is an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the error was quite simple actually, it's just that I parsed the array and then put it in another array with my for loop. I just had to delete  the for loop and everything was working.